# Display all values using group by SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

Here's the schema:

```
customers (customerID: integer, fName: string, lName: string)
items (itemID: integer, description: string, price: float)
orders (orderID: integer, itemID: integer, aID: integer, customerID: integer, date: date)
addresses (aID: integer, housenum: integer, streetName: string, town:string, state: string, zip:integer)
```

How do you List the town, first name, and last name of any customer who has shipped an item to the same town as another customer.

When I tried to use `GROUP BY` town, the output can only display the first customer in the group, instead of all that satisfy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about how you would answer the question.  Any such town has at least two customers making an order to it.  You can get this list using an aggregation query with a `having` clause:

```
           select town
           from orders o join
                addresses a
                on o.Aid = a.Aid
           group by town
           having count(distinct c.customerId) > 1
```

Now the only question is which customers have made orders to these towns:

```
select distinct a.town, c.fname, c.lname
from customer c join
     orders o
     on c.customerID = o.customerID join
     Addresses a
     on o.Aid = a.Aid
where town in (select town
               from orders o join
                    addresses a
                    on o.Aid = a.Aid
               group by town
               having count(distinct c.customerId) > 1
              )
```

The `distinct` on the first select is because there might be multiple records for each such customer.

Although this answers you question, it does not really answer a real business need.  Most states, for instance, have a locality called "Springfield".  You really need to take the state into account.  Or perhaps use zip code instead.  If this were a real business question, it would be swamped by customers shipping to say, New York City (assuming that the "town" field has consistent values.

Comment: Now I see how it works, but what if two customers have exactly same first name and exactly same last name? You can't just do select DISTINCT c.fname c.lname, right?

Comment: I wanted to do SELECT DISTINCT customerID, but the problem asks only to select town, fname and lname :(